# How to change the color of hud place of gray color

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

My question is the "How to change the color of the HUD in place of gray color"

- In hud their is a gray color for the hud.
- How to change the color of that color replace with off green color

[image]

in below image their is hud and how to change the gray color replace with another off green color

Thanks in advance.
Nimit Parekh.

Comment: This is not a built-in UIKit control - are you by any chance talking about this? https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: yes,i am use MBProgressHud but in that i want to change the background color into image which color is off black in place i inserting off green color.

Comment: Just go to the implementation file & modify color in init method :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I founding out the solution of this problem and implemented into my project.

In Following method is use into the MBProgressHud.m their is a manage the color of the Hud background color so the change color for that we change the value of the CGContextSetRGBFillColor argument change.

If apply this value then we gets the green color of the hud.

```
- (void)fillRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    float radius = 10.0f;

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 17.0/255, 64.0/255, 42.0/255, 0.8);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + radius, radius, 3 * M_PI / 2, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - radius, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - radius, radius, 0, M_PI / 2, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - radius, radius, M_PI / 2, M_PI, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + radius, radius, M_PI, 3 * M_PI / 2, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
HUD.color = [UIColor purpleColor];
...
```

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 3:**

```
let hud:MBProgressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)

hud.bezelView.color = UIColor.green // Your backgroundcolor

hud.bezelView.style = .solidColor // you should change the bezelview style to solid color.
```

Answer (score 6):

```
_mHud.bezelView.color = [UIColor blackColor];
_mHud.bezelView.style = MBProgressHUDBackgroundStyleSolidColor;
_mHud.contentColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 5):

MBProgressHUD.m has a "drawRect:(CGRect)rect" method where you will find the gray color set in CGContext function:

```
CGContextSetGrayFillColor (context, 0.0f, self.opacity);
```

You can just substitute CGContextSetGrayFillColor by another function that uses RGB (or other) color type:

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (context, 0/255.0f, 132/255.0f, 200/255.0f, 0.9f);
```

[Check complete CGContext reference here:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17057)

Comment: This worked for me **CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 0.4f, self.opacity);**

Answer (score 3):

Version 0.8 of MBProgressHud let's you set the color in its init method:
It is set to nil by default.

in MBProgressHUD.m:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
.
.
.
self.color = [UIColor greenColor];
```